# when i use semantic-ui-react Popup trigger, the pre message and current message all show

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

State of component:

`this.state = {
      pOM: props.pOM, // the return message of backend, as code is error
      isOpen: false
 }
<Popup open={this.state.isOpen} trigger={<Button className='btn-gre'>buy</Button>} on='click' content={this.state.pOM} hideOnScroll />`

When i click the button of buy, it will send the request to server, and get the return message,Popup will show it. Assume the current message is A, and when i click the button of buy in next time, it returns B message, but the Popup of Component will show all of them, the correct result that i want is just show B. Now i use the setTimeout to avoid this, but not perfect. So please tell me the better solution,thx

## Update:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
this.setState({
    pOM: nextProps.pOM
})
```

}

in componentWillReceiveProps function, i will call setState

Comment: It sounds like you may be adding messages to state, instead of replacing the current message. But you have not included enough code here to be able to tell. What does your click handler function look like, which I assume is where you are calling `setState()`?

Comment: @brianespinosa I update the code,thx